# Getting incorrect id for child item click

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, ontouch

I am getting incorrect id for child item click.

Fragment Class

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_checklist_groups_description, container, false);

        fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        mLinearListView = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.linear_ListView);

        //=========================================================================

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            V_ChecklistParentItemModel v_checklistParentItemModel = new V_ChecklistParentItemModel();
            v_checklistParentItemModel.setParentGroupID("" + (i + 1));
            v_checklistParentItemModel.setParentGroupName("Group Name " + i);

            if (i == 0) {
                v_checklistParentItemModel.setHasSubGroup(false);

                ArrayList<V_ChecklistChildItemModel> tempV_checklistChildItemModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    V_ChecklistChildItemModel v_checklistChildItemModel = new V_ChecklistChildItemModel();
                    v_checklistChildItemModel.setChildItemQuestionID("" + (j + 1));
                    v_checklistChildItemModel.setChildItemQuestionName("Description of Question " + (j + 1));
                    v_checklistChildItemModel.setChildQuestionID("" + index);
                    index++;

                    tempV_checklistChildItemModelArrayList.add(v_checklistChildItemModel);
                }

                v_checklistParentItemModel.setV_checklistChildItemModelArrayList(tempV_checklistChildItemModelArrayList);
            } else {
                v_checklistParentItemModel.setHasSubGroup(true);

                ArrayList<V_ChecklistSubGroupModel> tempV_checklistSubGroupModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                    V_ChecklistSubGroupModel v_checklistSubGroupModel = new V_ChecklistSubGroupModel();
                    v_checklistSubGroupModel.setSubGroupID("" + (j + 1));

                    if (j == 0) {
                        v_checklistSubGroupModel.setSubGroupName("Sub Group Name 2a");

                        ArrayList<V_ChecklistChildItemModel> tempV_checklistChildItemModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
                            V_ChecklistChildItemModel v_checklistChildItemModel = new V_ChecklistChildItemModel();
                            v_checklistChildItemModel.setChildItemQuestionID("" + (k + 1));
                            v_checklistChildItemModel.setChildItemQuestionName("Description of Question " + (k + 1));
                            v_checklistChildItemModel.setChildQuestionID("" + index);
                            index++;

                            tempV_checklistChildItemModelArrayList.add(v_checklistChildItemModel);
                        }

                        v_checklistSubGroupModel.setV_checklistChildItemModelArrayList(tempV_checklistChildItemModelArrayList);
                    } else {
                        v_checklistSubGroupModel.setSubGroupName("Sub Group Name 2b");

                        ArrayList<V_ChecklistChildItemModel> tempV_checklistChildItemModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                            V_ChecklistChildItemModel v_checklistChildItemModel = new V_ChecklistChildItemModel();
                            v_checklistChildItemModel.setChildItemQuestionID("" + (k + 1));
                            v_checklistChildItemModel.setChildItemQuestionName("Description of Question " + (k + 1));
                            v_checklistChildItemModel.setChildQuestionID("" + index);
                            index++;

                            tempV_checklistChildItemModelArrayList.add(v_checklistChildItemModel);
                        }

                        v_checklistSubGroupModel.setV_checklistChildItemModelArrayList(tempV_checklistChildItemModelArrayList);
                    }
                    tempV_checklistSubGroupModelArrayList.add(v_checklistSubGroupModel);
                }
                v_checklistParentItemModel.setV_checklistSubGroupModelArrayList(tempV_checklistSubGroupModelArrayList);
            }
            v_checklistParentItemModelArrayList.add(v_checklistParentItemModel);
        }


        //=========================================================================


        //Adds data into first row
        for (int i = 0; i < v_checklistParentItemModelArrayList.size(); i++) {
            Log.v("I : ", " " + i);
            LayoutInflater listInflater = null;
            listInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View mLinearView = listInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_cardview_checklist_groups_description_main_parent_item, null);

            final TextView mProductName = (TextView) mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            final RelativeLayout mImageArrowFirst = (RelativeLayout) mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.rlFirstArrow);
            final LinearLayout mLinearScrollSecond = (LinearLayout) mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.linear_scroll);

            //checkes if menu is already opened or not
            if (isFirstViewClick == false) {
                mLinearScrollSecond.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mImageArrowFirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.next_disable_icon);
            } else {
                mLinearScrollSecond.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mImageArrowFirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_down);
            }
            //Handles onclick effect on list item
            mImageArrowFirst.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (isFirstViewClick == false) {
                        isFirstViewClick = true;
                        mImageArrowFirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_down);
                        mLinearScrollSecond.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        isFirstViewClick = false;
                        mImageArrowFirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.next_disable_icon);
                        mLinearScrollSecond.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

            final String name = v_checklistParentItemModelArrayList.get(i).getParentGroupName();
            mProductName.setText(name);

            if (v_checklistParentItemModelArrayList.get(i).isHasSubGroup()) {
                //Adds data into second row
                for (int j = 0; j < v_checklistParentItemModelArrayList.get(i).getV_checklistSubGroupModelArrayList().size(); j++) {
                    Log.v("J : ", " " + j);
                    LayoutInflater inflater2 = null;
                    inflater2 = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View mLinearView2 = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.custom_cardview_checklist_groups_description_child_parent_item, null);

                    TextView mSubItemName = (TextView) mLinearView2.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
                    final RelativeLayout mLinearSecondArrow = (RelativeLayout) mLinearView2.findViewById(R.id.linearSecond);
                    final RelativeLayout mImageArrowSecond = (RelativeLayout) mLinearView2.findViewById(R.id.rlSecondArrow);
                    final LinearLayout mLinearScrollThird = (LinearLayout) mLinearView2.findViewById(R.id.linear_scroll_third);
                    final LinearLayout linearLayoutMain = (LinearLayout) mLinearView2.findViewById(R.id.llMain);

                    if (i == 0) {
                        mLinearSecondArrow.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.main_parent));
                        mImageArrowSecond.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        linearLayoutMain.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
                    } else {
                        mLinearSecondArrow.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.child_parent));
                        mImageArrowSecond.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        if (i == 1) {
                            linearLayoutMain.setPadding(20, 8, 0, 0);
                        } else {
                            linearLayoutMain.setPadding(15, 8, 0, 0);
                        }
                    }

                    //checkes if menu is already opened or not
                    if (isSecondViewClick == false) {
                        mLinearScrollThird.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mImageArrowSecond.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.next_disable_icon);
                    } else {
                        mLinearScrollThird.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mImageArrowSecond.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_down);
                    }

                    //Handles onclick effect on list item
                    if (i == 0) {
                        final int finalI1 = i;
                        final int finalJ1 = j;
                        mLinearSecondArrow.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                bundle.putString("groupName", v_checklistParentItemModelArrayList.get(finalI1).getParentGroupName());
                                bundle.putInt("itemCount", 3);
                                bundle.putSerializable("alldata", checklist_groupNamePojoArrayList);
                                pageNumber = 0;
                                bundle.putInt("pageNumber", pageNumber);

                                ChecklistGroupsQuestionsMainDialogFragment checklistGroupsQuestionsMainDialogFragment = new ChecklistGroupsQuestionsMainDialogFragment();
                                checklistGroupsQuestionsMainDialogFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                                checklistGroupsQuestionsMainDialogFragment.setTargetFragment(current, 101);
                                checklistGroupsQuestionsMainDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, getResources().getString(R.string.sd_project_list_screen_name));

                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        mImageArrowSecond.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                                if (isSecondViewClick == false) {
                                    isSecondViewClick = true;
                                    mImageArrowSecond.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_down);
                                    mLinearScrollThird.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                } else {
                                    isSecondViewClick = false;
                                    mImageArrowSecond.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.next_disable_icon);
                                    mLinearScrollThird.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    final String catName = v_checklistParentItemModelArrayList.get(i).getV_checklistSubGroupModelArrayList().get(j).getSubGroupName();
                    mSubItemName.setText(catName);
                    //Adds items in subcategories
                    for (int k = 0; k < v_checklistParentItemModelArrayList.get(i).getV_checklistSubGroupModelArrayList().get(j).getV_checklistChildItemModelArrayList().size(); k++) {
                        Log.v("K : ", " " + k);
                        LayoutInflater inflater3 = null;
                        inflater3 = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        View mLinearView3 = inflater3.inflate(R.layout.custom_cardview_checklist_groups_description_child_item, null);
                        TextView mItemName = (TextView) mLinearView3.findViewById(R.id.textViewItemName);
                        final String itemName = v_checklistParentItemModelArrayList.get(i).getV_checklistSubGroupModelArrayList().get(j).getV_checklistChildItemModelArrayList().get(k).getChildItemQuestionName();
                        mItemName.setText(itemName);

                        mLinearScrollThird.addView(mLinearView3);

                        final int finalI = i;
                        final int finalJ = j;
                        final int finalK = k;
                        mLinearScrollThird.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                bundle.putString("groupName", v_checklistParentItemModelArrayList.get(finalI).getParentGroupName());
                                bundle.putInt("itemCount", v_checklistParentItemModelArrayList.get(finalI).getV_checklistSubGroupModelArrayList().get(finalJ).getV_checklistChildItemModelArrayList().size());
//                            bundle.putSerializable("questionData", group2bQuestionList);
                                bundle.putSerializable("alldata", checklist_groupNamePojoArrayList);
                                pageNumber = finalI + finalJ + finalK + 1;
                                bundle.putInt("pageNumber", pageNumber);

                                Log.v("====ugugugu==", "===ijhbjhbjh===");
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Page No. " + v_checklistParentItemModelArrayList.get(finalI).getV_checklistSubGroupModelArrayList().get(finalJ).getV_checklistChildItemModelArrayList().get(finalK).getChildQuestionID(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                ChecklistGroupsQuestionsMainDialogFragment checklistGroupsQuestionsMainDialogFragment = new ChecklistGroupsQuestionsMainDialogFragment();
                                checklistGroupsQuestionsMainDialogFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                                checklistGroupsQuestionsMainDialogFragment.setTargetFragment(current, 101);
                                checklistGroupsQuestionsMainDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, getResources().getString(R.string.check_list_groups_question_screen_name));

                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    mLinearScrollSecond.addView(mLinearView2);
                }
                mLinearListView.addView(mLinearView);
            } else {
                //Adds items in subcategories
                for (int k = 0; k < v_checklistParentItemModelArrayList.get(i).getV_checklistChildItemModelArrayList().size(); k++) {
                    Log.v("K : ", " " + k);
                    LayoutInflater inflater3 = null;
                    inflater3 = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View mLinearView3 = inflater3.inflate(R.layout.custom_cardview_checklist_groups_description_child_item, null);
                    final LinearLayout mLinearScrollThird = (LinearLayout) mLinearView3.findViewById(R.id.linear_scroll_third);
                    TextView mItemName = (TextView) mLinearView3.findViewById(R.id.textViewItemName);
                    final String itemName = v_checklistParentItemModelArrayList.get(i).getV_checklistChildItemModelArrayList().get(k).getChildItemQuestionName();
                    mItemName.setText(itemName);

                    final int finalI = i;
                    final int finalK = k;
                    mLinearScrollThird.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            bundle.putString("groupName", v_checklistParentItemModelArrayList.get(finalI).getParentGroupName());
                            bundle.putInt("itemCount", v_checklistParentItemModelArrayList.get(finalI).getV_checklistChildItemModelArrayList().size());
                            bundle.putSerializable("alldata", checklist_groupNamePojoArrayList);
                            bundle.putInt("pageNumber", 1);

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Page No. " + v_checklistParentItemModelArrayList.get(finalI).getV_checklistChildItemModelArrayList().get(finalK).getChildQuestionID(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            ChecklistGroupsQuestionsMainDialogFragment checklistGroupsQuestionsMainDialogFragment = new ChecklistGroupsQuestionsMainDialogFragment();
                            checklistGroupsQuestionsMainDialogFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                            checklistGroupsQuestionsMainDialogFragment.setTargetFragment(current, 101);
                            checklistGroupsQuestionsMainDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, getResources().getString(R.string.check_list_groups_question_screen_name));

                            return false;
                        }
                    });

                    mLinearScrollSecond.addView(mLinearView3);
                }
                mLinearListView.addView(mLinearView);
            }
        }

        //==============================================================================


        return itemView;
    }
```

I have assigned Child Question ID using setChildQuestionID(). For Group Name 0, I get 0, 1, 2 on each child click. However, for Group Name 1, I get 4 for Sub Group Name 2a & 7 for Sub Group Name 2b for each of there child item click. Ideally, it should return whatever I set for them.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to get 0, 1, 2 for child clicks in group name 1? As far as I can tell, you're going to have to re-set the value of index to 0 to get that. At least, assuming you've defined index = 0 somewhere outside your outermost for-loop (I can't see where in your code you've set the value of index). Right now in Group 0, you have:

```
                        for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
                        V_ChecklistChildItemModel v_checklistChildItemModel = new V_ChecklistChildItemModel();
                        v_checklistChildItemModel.setChildItemQuestionID("" + (k + 1));
                        v_checklistChildItemModel.setChildItemQuestionName("Description of Question " + (k + 1));
                        v_checklistChildItemModel.setChildQuestionID("" + index);
                        index++;
```

If index was 0 to start with, the value of index is now greater than 0. You don't set it back to 0, so when you get to the next cycle through your top-level for loop, the value of index is already > 0. If you want to start over at index = 0 in Group 1, you'll have to set the value of index back to 0.

In other words, you are returning exactly what you set for the questionIDs, but I think you're setting a number that you didn't want to set.